# What causes this LTspice error message?

Tags: ltspice

LTspice error message:

> Voltage source VSS and voltage source VDD are paralleled making an over-defined circuit matrix.
> You will need to correct the circuit or add some series resistance.

[image]

Paralleled voltage sources error in LTspice.

Answer (score 6):

Your design has all sorts of short-circuits:

[image]

I've marked some. There are possibly more...

Comment: funny... I use a diagram like this as bonus trick interview question ... without the red circles

Answer (score 3):

Follow down from VDD to VSS, you have the two nets connected by wires.  You also have Vin shorted to these networks.  Everywhere there is a dot in the intersection between two lines, the lines are connected.

Answer (score 2):

Right down the center you have a concatenation of wires connecting VDD to VSS. A "short circuit".